# Example of three.js KeyframeTrack with smoothing (cubic interpolation)

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, keyframe, cubic

I looking for some clarity on how to implement smoothing (a.k.a. cubic interpolation) on a three.js animation KeyframeTrack. From my testing, parsing the interpolation method in the KeyframeTrack constructor is insufficient.

```
var position = new THREE.VectorKeyframeTrack(
    '.position',
    [0, 1],
    [
        plane.position.x,
        plane.position.y,
        plane.position.z,
        1.25 * plane.position.x,
        1.25 * plane.position.y,
        1.25 * plane.position.z
    ],
    THREE.InterpolateSmooth
);
position.createInterpolant();

var clip = new THREE.AnimationClip('Action', 3, [
    position
]);

that.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(plane);

var action = that.mixer.clipAction(clip);
action.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
action.startAt(0);                // delay in seconds
action.clampWhenFinished = true;
action.play();
```